# Match whole word from partial-word search string

Tags: php, preg-match, cpu-word

Could you help me to create a pattern, which matches whole words, containing a specific part? For example, if I have a text string `Perform a regular expression match` and if I search for `express`, it should give me `expression`, if I search for `form`, it should give me `Perform` and so on.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\b(express\w+)\b/', $string, $matches); // matches expression
preg_match('/\b(\w*form\w*)\b/', $string, $matches); // matches perform,
                                                     // formation, unformatted
```

Where:

- `\b` is a word boundary
- `\w+` is one or more "word" character<sup>*</sup>
- `\w*` is zero or more "word" characters

See the manual on [escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for PCRE.

---

<sup>* Note: although not really a "word character", the underscore `_` is also included int the character class `\w`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

This matches 'Perform':

```
\b(\w*form\w*)\b
```

This matches 'expression':

```
\b(\w*express\w*)\b
```