# Regex: Match whole word in string PHP

Tags: php, regex

My sample string is

> Indian India's India.

I want to match only "India" as a whole word. My regular expression is `/\b(india)\b/i`.

But this is giving me 2 matches. one in "India's" and other in last word.

To avoid getting India in India's, I used this regex `/\b(india)[^'a-z]\b/i`. But this regex is matching "India." (Notice the dot)

I only want to match India. How can I achieve this?

I am doing this in PHP.

Comment: see ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722007/php-preg-match-to-find-whole-words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
\bIndia(?=$|\s)
```

- `(?=$|\s)` Positive Lookahead `$` assert position at end of a line or `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

If you want to allow `,(comma)` or `.(dot)` then you can simply use

```
\bIndia(?=[.,]|$|\s)
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/oC4kC8/1)

Answer (score 3):

You need to just modify the regex:

```
\b(India)\b(?!\')
```