# Connect to specific network SSID (hotspot) when app active

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, ondemand, ad-hoc-network

Before I start this journey in Android I want to know if it is possible to connect to a specific network SSID when an app is active and restore the previous network settings when exit the app or when the device go sleep.

---

**The reason I want to this:**

- An app for a specific device that can be reachable via adhoc
  connection;
- No need to hook into an existing network (adhoc device needs no
  config), so user friendly;
- The app can use the all of the features of WIFI;
- Device is isolated from the internet and provides own network

---

**The idea:**

- The app discovers the available WIFI-networks when no device is
  configurated yet;
- The device can be found via an SSID prefix, for example 'umix_' and user can select the unique correct name after the prefix, for example: 123456 (= umix_123456);
- Once successfully connected, this name will be used to connect;
- User can use the device via WIFI;
- When exit the app or device go to sleep it reconnects to previous network;
- When the app is active on wake up, it reconnects to the device it's network.

---

Maybe the described behaviour looks like a bluetooth connection, however, it is not because it is WIFI, better bandwidth for example and server facilities. However, the easy of use for it's user is similar to bluetooth, I want to achieve this.

Because I cannot find any info on this on the net, I ask it here. Is what I want possible anyway? Any directions, links, code examples?

Comment: These links might be helpful :) [Getting the available wifi lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android) [using preg match to filter SSID starting from umix_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722007/php-preg-match-to-find-whole-words) [Connecting/Disconnecting to the wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: @DipakPoudel: Thanks for the link, take a look at it.