# How to use regex to find exactly a word or string in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex to find a word or some words in a string. 
For example:

```
if(preg_match("~\bbet\b~",$text) !== false)  // want to find "bet" in string
```

Mean i want to check if it there is **bet** in that string ($text)

But, *if $text = "there is difference between this string and that string",* it will return true.

Now, i want, for example these will return true:

> $text = "I bet he's a virgin!"
>
> $text = "Bet you're glad you flew out there."

But this sentence will return false

> $text = "there is difference between this string and that string"

Or 1 more example for harder string:

I want to find "**hi**" in string
But not **hi** in **this**

It will return true if

> $text = "hi";

But return false if

> $text = "this";

Comment: There is no match [here](https://regex101.com/r/5TufES/1), in `there is difference between this string and that string`. `\bbet\b` only searches for `bet` as a whole word. Use `"~\bbet\b~i"` to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP preg_match to find whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722007/php-preg-match-to-find-whole-words)

Comment: Also a dupe of [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

Answer (score 0):

For `bet` to return true, we can use a lookahead with word boundary and `i` flag, with an expression similar to:

```
.*(?=\bbet\b).*
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/m8V4AK/1/)

```
$re = '/.*(?=\bbet\b).*/mi';
$str = 'I bet he\'s a virgin!
Bet you\'re glad you flew out there.
I betty he\'s a virgin!
Betty you\'re glad you flew out there.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

We can similarly check for `hi` and `this`:

```
.*(?=\bhi\b).*
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Pgp6mL/1/)

#### TEST 2

```
$re = '/.*(?=\bhi\b).*/mi';
$str = 'there is difference between this string and that string
hi there, is difference between that string and other string false?

';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```